# convert long URL to short URL codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, url, short-url

I am using codeigniter and need to convert a long URL of a website to short URL's like in Google URL shorter...i cant find anything online for this .Please Help

eg: http://www.youtube.com/ to http://goo.gl/fUDP

I am already able to put the long URL's into the database and retrieve it but now i need to convert these URL's to short URL's and display to users

MODEL:

```
'URL'=> $this->input->post('URL')
```

VIEW:

```
URL:<input type="text" name="URL">
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  What are you asking us?  What do you want from us?

Comment: I am unable to find how to implement it

Comment: URL shorteners aren't too hard.  You just need to make a unique ID for each URL (such as `fUDP`) and add that to the db row (make sure it's indexed).  Then when someone goes to the short URL, look up the key and get the full URL.

Comment: but again when i retrieve the data i am supposed to click on the short url and go to the given long url as we do it in google url shorter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As People are looking for an answer i would like to post the best comment i found that will help:

URL shorteners aren't too hard. You just need to make a unique ID for each URL (such as fUDP) and add that to the db row (make sure it's indexed). Then when someone goes to the short URL, look up the key and get the full URL. –By @Rocket Hazmat

Answer (score 0):

There is something called as Routing in Codeigniter. 
Basically, it is a way of customizing the URL according to your needs.

Instead of opting for other tools, I would like you to read the Codeigniter page first:

http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html

This will give you an idea on how to shorten the URL. Sometimes, the function names can be a bit messy but you can fix that by Routing.

Comment: hey, i dont want the codeigniter url,i have a text input wherein the users can put the url where their video or audio is put like youtube.com/... or soundcloud.com/... etc... so as these urls get bigger each time i need to shorten them and link them as well,i.e when the url is clicked it should go to that page

Comment: then you will have to use the third party tools. There is no other option

Comment: You can check @Rocket Hazmat's comment that answers the question